# Android 4.4.2 rendering issue

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing an android project for myself. Now i am stuck with this weird issue. My edit text control in my android project is rendering weird. I don't know why. It works fine in android M. I provided the xml code  and screenshot below.

**Screenshot**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="bridge.com.fame.signup_activity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/profilepicsignupholder"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic_holder_layout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/profile_pic"

            />




    </RelativeLayout>



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/profile_pic_holder_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userNameText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:hint="Re-Enter Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/reenterpasswordText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_auth"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="Sign Me Up"
        android:id="@+id/signup_button_form"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/reenterpasswordText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/reenterpasswordText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/reenterpasswordText" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/userNameText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/passwordText"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:singleLine="false" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is it supposed to look like?

Comment: see the preview . i want the factory default edit text comes with android studio.

Answer (score 1):

try to add `android:stateListAnimator="@null"`to the editext where you find such issues.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'
```

change build tools to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

Comment: it works perfectly and it solves bunch of other issues. I was having with rendering some icons and buttons. + it fixes an installation issue the was failing to install on a device running android version 5.*